# How Do I Set A Variable to Cell Value that has Line Breaks, and Return Variable in HTML Template?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to pass a cell value that contains line breaks into an HTML template for an outbound e-mail I am able to grab the values, but the line break isn't populating correctly. In this example, I'm using `var row` as my active row, and the cell I want to grab is index 36.

```
var notesUpdateHTML = row[36].replace(/\n/g,"<br>")
```

Index 36 is being updated by this code, which is grabbing the new update text, and appending the old update text(s) below it.

```
// setting notes values 
    var newNotes = developerQueueSheet.getRange("E7").getValue();
    var oldNotes = developerQueueSheet.getRange("I2").getValue();
    var newNotesDateFormat = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), spreadsheetTimeZone, "M.dd");
    var newNotesFormat = newNotesDateFormat + ' - ' + sessionEmail + ' // ' + newNotes
    var notesUpdate
    if (newNotes == '') {
        notesUpdate = oldNotes
    } else if (newNotes != '') {
        notesUpdate = newNotesFormat + "\r" + "\n" + oldNotes
    }
    eSheet.getRange(startRow + i, 37).setValue(notesUpdate);
```

Inside the HTML Template, I am able to grab the notes and separate them into the newest update and the older ones. However, they just return as one long text blob.
[image]

I did try referencing [the only other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524540/htmlservice-table-not-supporting-line-breaks-and-hyperlinks-from-spreadsheet) I could find on my question, but still can't get it to return correctly.

Any advice/direction you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
**Update**

Here's the code that I'm using to send the e-mail:

```
var MyToAddress;
            var MyCCAddress
            var MySubject;
            var MyTemplate;
          var processOwner
            if (row[15] == "Existing Automation/Database" & row[17] == "Error") {
                MyTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('errorEmailBody.html')
                MySubject = "TCS Automation - A User Has Identified a Potential Error!"
                MyToAddress = currentDatabaseEmail
                MyCCAddress = row[14]

            MyTemplate.row = row;
            var messageBody = MyTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
            var emailAddress = MyToAddress;
            var ccAddress = MyCCAddress;
            var subject = MySubject;
            MailApp.sendEmail({
                to: emailAddress,
                cc: ccAddress,
                subject: subject,
                htmlBody: messageBody,
                replyTo: emailAddress,
                noReply: true
            })
```

Here's the inside of the HTML template file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {color:#fff ;background: #8E8E8F}
h2 {color:#fff ;background: #012F60}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Your project has been has a new update from <?= row[49] ?>.<br>

<p><b>Status</b><br>
<i><?= row[54] ?></i></p>

<p><b>ETA Update (If Applicable)</b><br>
<i><?= row[60] ?></i></p>

<p><b>New Notes</b><br>
<i><?= row[58] ?></i></p>

<p><b>Historical Notes</b><br>
<i><?= row[59] ?></i></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you share how you create your HTML template and also the code that sends the email? I use `MailApp` with `htmlBody` options and it introduces break at `<br>` tags in the email.

Comment: @JackBrown I've updated the OP with additional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using printing scriptlets (ie `<?= row[59] ?>`), google scripts automatically adds escape characters to [protect against XSS attacks](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/security). This is a known behavior and has been documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets)

In cases exactly like yours, where you are trying to add HTML elements dynamically, you can use [force-printing scriplets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets) (i.e `<?!= row[59] ?>`.

> As a general rule, use printing scriptlets rather than force-printing
>   scriptlets unless you know that you need to print HTML or JavaScript
>   unchanged.

So your final HTML code will look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {color:#fff ;background: #8E8E8F}
h2 {color:#fff ;background: #012F60}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Your project has been has a new update from <?= row[49] ?>.<br>

<p><b>Status</b><br>
<i><?= row[54] ?></i></p>

<p><b>ETA Update (If Applicable)</b><br>
<i><?= row[60] ?></i></p>

<p><b>New Notes</b><br>
<i><?= row[58] ?></i></p>

<p><b>Historical Notes</b><br>
<i><?!= row[59] ?></i></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that completely fixed it. I wasn't sure what it meant to force print it with contextual escaping. Now, I understand. Thanks so much for the quick help!